# Circular Referencing between projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have built two projects in my VS solution. One is a MVC web applicaition and other one is a standard C# windows form project. I want to transfer data both ways. For exmaple the input from my MVC web application to the form and then output back to my web application from the C# form project. However, I can only do refrenceing from one side and access the static variblias of only one project from another. To achieve my goal, I need to do circular referencing which VS is not allowing me. Is there a workaround to my solution.

PS: My main goal is to access all the static members of every class into every other class in my whole solution.

Comment: Move the shared classes to a new class library project and reference that project from both the MVC and the WinForms projects.

Comment: Hi, There are no shared classes. Just the data dependency between two projects. My MVC web application can't show output until my C# project returns it.

Comment: Won't all those static variables be a problem when you have more than 1 user accessing your MVC site at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the static functions in a separate library and then reference that from windows or web application. That way you will also know what are common functions and what functions are specific to those feature or class.

It is not a good design to let "access all the static members of every class into every other class". It violate OOPS principles.

If its shared data save it to any repository and access it from there from both of your application.